Messagebox.askyesno Not Working in Spyder IDE
I had the messagebox.askyesno function (from tkinter) working when I was using it from the Spyder standalone install. However, when I switched to the Python interpreter from Anaconda, the messagebox no longer popped up. There is no error message; the code just gets stuck as if it's waiting for the user to select an answer in the messagebox, but there is no longer any messagebox.
The relevant code looks like this:
from tkinter import messagebox

writechoice = messagebox.askyesno(title='Write to File', message='Would you like to write this table to 
the Final Excel File?')

I have ensured that Tkinter is installed in Anaconda, but with no error messages, I really am not sure what to troubleshoot.

Your code works fine with Python 3.12.4 in Windows. Note that the title says it does not work in Spyder, but the question says it works in Spyder.  So which one is the issue actually?

Are you sure that the messagebox didn't just appear behind some other window?

Okay, I was able to find the messagebox by searching for it in my Task Manager... it still isn't popping up the way it's supposed to, though.

To answer your question, acw1668, it worked perfectly in Spyder until I rerouted the Python Interpreter through Anaconda.
